# Can I get a "stack trace" that traces all async calls, with Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Consider code like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

foo() {
  new Timer(onesec, bar);
}

bar() {
  throw "from bar";
}

const onesec = const Duration(seconds:1);

main() {
  runZoned(() {
  new Timer(onesec, foo);
  },
  onError: (e, stackTrace) => print(stackTrace));
}
```

How can I tell that `bar` was "called" by `foo` in the `stackTrace` that I print out?

I'd like to see something like:

```
bar
...
foo
...
main
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [stack_trace package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stack_trace). It uses zones to keep track of asynchronous callbacks. Capturing stack traces for every asynchronous callback is expensive, but for debugging it is definitely worth it.

Example output from the package:

```
http://dartlang.org/foo/bar.dart 10:11  Foo.<fn>.bar
http://dartlang.org/foo/baz.dart        Foo.<fn>.bar
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
http://dartlang.org/foo/bang.dart 10:11  Foo.<fn>.bar
http://dartlang.org/foo/quux.dart        Foo.<fn>.bar
```

According to the [doc](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#stack_trace/stack_trace.Chain), the easiest way to get these traces is to use `Chain.capture`.