# Can not get the repeat to work in a dart polymer webapp

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

1. Created a default polymere web app
2. Delete a few lines of main_app.html to this

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="main-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

3. change the content of main_app.dart like this

```js
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';


class Project extends Observable
{
    Project(this.name, this.dateCreated);
    @published var name;
    @published var dateCreated;
}

@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
    
    /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
    MainApp.created() : super.created()
    {
        
    }
    
      /// Called when an instance of main-app is inserted into the DOM.
      attached() {
        createModelObjects();
        super.attached();
      }
    
      /// Called when an instance of main-app is removed from the DOM.
      detached() {
        super.detached();
      }
    
  @published List<Project> projects = new List();
  
  void createModelObjects() {
      projects.add(new Project("InterSections Santa Rosa South inspection", new DateTime.now()));
      projects.add(new Project("Playground Inspections Healdsburg ", new DateTime.now()));
      projects.add(new Project("Pothole inspection Bloomfield Rd Sebastopol", new DateTime.now()));
  }
}
```

4. Set a breakpoint at createModel Objects and run index.html in Dartium or javascript. The breakpoint hits three time, why?
5. How to I see a trace when a breakpoint hits in a webapp/dart editor.
   [image]
6. Now to my second question, change the template in main_app.html to this:

```html
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    p {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 80px 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    </style>
    
      <table>
          <tr template repeat="{{project in projects}}">
            <td> <p>Name and Date
                          {{name}}
                          {{dateCreated}}</p></td>
                
          </tr>
      </table>
   </template>
```

7. Restart and I see nothing - I would expect a Table of Project elements
   what do I miss?
8. I run the debugging tools in dartium and see the following elements
   How can I look into the code fragment?
   [image]
9. Not sure what the recommended way is to debug this situation. Any help out there?

Comment: What Polymer version are you using?

Comment: 0.15.5+4 (thats what I see under the packages folder). I just reinstalled Dart Editor. I am running under Windows 7

Comment: I  think the bindings `{{name}}` should be `{{project. name}}` (same for dateCreated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4) I can't reproduce

5) When the debugger hits a breakpoint the Debugger view shows the call stack. Seems obvious, therefore hard to explain. You don't see the call stack in the debugger view or you don't have the debugger view at all? 
To get better stack traces check [How to get the full stack trace for async execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013591) (print only)

6, 7) This worked for me

```dart
<table>
  <tr template repeat="{{project in projects}}">
    <td><p>Name and Date
      {{project.name}}
      {{project.dateCreated}}</p></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

The `project` field needs to be an observable collection so Polymer gets notification about changes to the list

```dart
@published List<Project> projects = new List();
```

8) You can't 
If you inspect the `<div hidden>` above you find the used template details of this element.

9)
I got an exception when I tried your code without `{{project....}}`

Additional hint:

use `@observable` instead of `@published`. You can also use `@observable` instead of @published if you bind to the field only from within this component.

Comment: To Number 4) sorry this is a stupid user error. I worked to long in Visual Studi and assumed that the play button is also the continoue button. Hitting it a few times makes it appear like the breakpoint gets hit over an over again. Plain old User error

Comment: To Number 5) I added a image above how my debugger window looks like. I dont see a trace.

Comment: The upper half is the trace. What do you miss here?

Comment: To Number 6/7 
I added project.name and project.dateCreated but my dartium windows shows nothing (blank white screen). I get no exception. A toast message shows "Waiting for local host" . Strange

Comment: When you remove the repeat and just add text like `<div>sometext</div>` does this appear on your page? Do you have the `index.html` in your `pubspec.yaml` polymer transformer entry_points section? I assumed you have because you stated that it works without the repeat.

Comment: To Number 9) don't see any exception. Something must be wrong with my environment. I reinstalled Dart editor already

Comment: I didn't get any errors when I used Polymer 0.16.0. I reported this already. I switched back to Polymer 0.15.? and I got an exception in the output window. You can also check the `pub serve` view for errors.

Comment: What happens sometimes when you start with Dart is that the pub cache gets corrupted. You can try `pub cache repair` on the command line.

Comment: ok I added just <div>sometext</div> there is no repeat anymore and it works but only when I commented out all the project.add calls in main_app.dart.

Comment: That sounds very weird.  Can you please post your `pubspec.lock` file somewhere? Maybe a gist at Github or Pastebin or something.

Comment: Deleted c:\Users\jhilger\AppData\Roaming\Pub\ and tried again. Now I can leave projects.add in the code and a simple  <div>sometext</div> works. 

This still does not work. polymere is 0.15.5+4


<table>
  <tr template repeat="{{project in projects}}">
    <td><p>Name and Date
      {{project.name}}
      {{project.dateCreated}}</p></td>

  </tr>
</table>

Comment: Here is the pubspec.lock
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5BC80ECDD80B39BE!50334&authkey=!ACDuyNvnikVOGiI&ithint=file%2clock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73368/discussion-between-ride-sun-and-gunter-zochbauer).