# Stack Trace for Dart in WebStorm not linked with code

Tags: dart, webstorm

The lines in stack trace for a Dart application being developed in latest WebStorm EAP (141.224) are not linked with the location (line and position) in my code. It does have links for the core Dart library. The screenshot below is an example.

Is there a setting that will allow me to do this, or this is simply a bug in the EAP version?

[image: screenshot from WebStorm console panel]

**Update:**
After using the `stack_trace` package the readability is improved but the links to **my** code are still missing. See below.

[image: screenshot from WebStorm console panel after using stack_trace package]

**Update 2:**
There is a bug report about closely related issue but it is reported as fixed:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13532

Comment: Sorry to hear about the trouble. Definitely file bugs at youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default the stack traces are not connected through async calls.

See [How to get the full stack trace for async execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013591) for a solution/workaround.

Comment: No luck, @GünterZöchbauer, The readability of the stack trace is improved but there are still no links for **my** code. I am adding an image to my own question to show how it looks after using the `stack_trace` package.

Comment: Can you add example code that allows to reproduce it?

Comment: I will try to add some code but I strongly suspect it has nothing to do with the code. In Dart Editor, it works fine. So, even if I want to use only WebStorm, I have to keep switching between Dart Editor and WebStorm if there are exceptions being thrown.

Comment: You get better stack strace in DartEditor?

Comment: It is the same but it has active links, on which I can click and jump to the exact line throwing the exception. In WebStorm, such "hyperlinks" are missing.

Comment: I see. You should create a bug report (if there isn't one already). I asked for code to see if I can find a way to get a better stack trace for your specific situation..

Comment: Günter, please see my update in the original question. It seems, you had reported the bug, last year.

Comment: I made so many bug reports that I completely lost track of them ;-)
Is your question about this print output missing clickable links? I thought it is about not listing entries which reference your custom code but only Dart core code.

Comment: The stack trace does list my code if it is involved but the lines are not clickable, as a result I have to manually scroll through my code to the line number indicated.

Comment: I see. Then it's just the bug you references. Did you upvote?

Comment: I cannot since it is reported as fixed.

Comment: Just create a new one.

Comment: I did. Thank you. You are a great help and I appreciate your support.