# Custom angular2 validator in Dart giving console error

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am attempting to make an angular2 validator using Dart:

#### .dart

```
class CustomValidators {

 static Map<String, bool> wordValidator(Control ctrl)
  {
    if( matches(ctrl.value, r"^[A-Za-z]{1,}[\'\ \,\.\-]*[a-z]*$"))
    {
      return {'wordValidator': true};
    }
  }
 }
```

where matches has the following definition:

#### matches

```
/// check if string matches the pattern.
bool matches(String str, pattern) {
  RegExp re = new RegExp(pattern);
  return re.hasMatch(str);
}
```

When I attempt to run the validation I get the following in the console

#### console ouput

```
    (anonymous function)    
  ERROR CONTEXT:
    (anonymous function)    
  DartObject
    (anonymous function)    
  <
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
EXCEPTION: Invalid argument(s) in [AST]
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument(s)
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
#0      _JSSyntaxRegExp.hasMatch (dart:core-patch/regexp_patch.dart:174)
#1      matches (package:validator/src/validator.dart:53:13)
#2      CustomValidators.wordValidator (package:epimss_ng2_shared/validators.dart:83:9)
...
```

`(package:epimss_ng2_shared/validators.dart:83:9)` points to the matches method above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without a full repo case.

I assume `ctrl.value` returns `null` or some other non-`String` value.

Comment: Your assumption lead me to do some investigations. It turned out that the problem was a model property that was null. After initializing all model properties to an empty string the error disappears. Interestingly, the stack trace gave no indication about the model and pointed to the validator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013591/how-to-get-the-full-stack-trace-for-async-execution might create better stack traces (not sure if it helps in this case)