# Is there support for predefined macros in DART

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-webui

Does DART support predefined macros such as:

```
__LINE__
```

or

```
__FUNCTION__
```

The reason for asking is that the transformer DART2JS makes the console log not useful as all the logs shows: js_primitives.dart:30

[update BasE]

When using the transformer dart2js, `print("hello world");` will result in:

```
JS('void', r'console.log(#)', "hello world);
```

to be invoked from function: printString(String string)
residing in the library dart2js._js_primitives

This results that the console.log message always contains the same line number over and over again wherever in the DART code a `print();` is used. (As console.log will add automatically the filename and line-number to the console display of the wrapper function residing in dart2js._js_primitives)
As the current implementation of adding file-name and line-number to the console.log message is useless, it would have been nice if there would be another method that allows to display additional information.

As example, `print("hello world" __FUNCTION__ __LINE__);` would result in additional debug information that can be more useful.

Comment: No, there is not, but I don't see how that existing (or not) applies to your question about console logging. Can you try asking what exactly you want to see changed instead?

Comment: Just added more text to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
void main() {
  print(StackTrace.current);
}
```

to get better information about the source of the error

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e74cd3c98dddefca9514bf2e85d9132a)

You can also run your code in a custom zone and define a custom print method for that zone. See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/Zone/print.html

Comment: Hi Gunter, Just tried your suggestion. It generates lots of information. and indeed on the second line it prints the filename and line number.

Error
    at Object.StackTrace_current (core_patch.dart:680)
    at testCase_readWrite.dart:59
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (async_patch.dart:213)
...
...

Comment: You might be able to reduce the noise using the `terse` function from the `stack_trace` package https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013592/217408. It might cause some overhead in memory usage and performance, but I find it often useful for debugging.

Comment: By using:
`print(new Trace.from(StackTrace.current).terse);`
will give:
`main.dart.js 13338:40  Object.StackTrace_current
main.dart.js 68378:44  <fn>
main.dart.js 6883:15   _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected`
It strips out the function name

Comment: Using: `print(new Trace.from(StackTrace.current).vmTrace);`
results in:
`#1      Object.StackTrace_current (http://localhost:64250/main.dart.js:13338:40)
#2      <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:64250/main.dart.js:68380:44)
#3      _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:64250/main.dart.js:6883:15)`
It also removed the function name.

Comment: Using: `print(new Trace.from(StackTrace.current).original);` will give the best result for me.
`Error
    at Object.StackTrace_current (core_patch.dart:680)
    at testCase_readWrite.dart:66
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (async_patch.dart:213)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems what you are looking for is source maps that dart2js creates, that contain the information needed to recreate line numbers in original dart files, from the javascript locations.